# Alternative source for nltk data

Tags: python-3.x, nltk

I am trying to install the nltk corpora through these commands as mentioned in the documentation -

```
import nltk
nltk.download()
```

However, I am doing this from my stupid organization which has blocked github, which is what the download function above tries to connect to.

Is there an alternate repository for the nltk data from where I can try this out? Trying to whitelist github and associated websites will only get tangled in red tape.

Thank you

Comment: Having the same problem. Did you sort this?

Comment: Look at the solution below. Does that also not work?

Comment: Another blocked source :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try downloading the Arch Linux package for nltk, which contains all the files you need.

1. Download the package from [Archlinux packages website](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/any/nltk-data/), using the *Download from Mirror* link in the *Package Actions* box on the right, or you can just use [this link](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/any/nltk-data/download/).
2. Extract the file (it is an xzipped tar archive). I used ark on linux, not sure what is the appropriate software for your system (on windows 7zip and winrar should be able to handle this).
3. You find the files in the folder `usr/share/nltk_data`.
4. Move the `nltk_data` folder to the [appropriate path](http://www.nltk.org/data.html#command-line-installation) on your machine.

Comment: This is the right answer for my problem. If any other Linux distribution also has the package zip, please mention in the comments

Answer (score 0):

There was a brief period when GitHub actually blocked all fetches of `nltk_data`, resulting in [issue 1787](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/1787) which is still open and contains many workarounds, and plans to avoid relying on GitHub hosting.

The current 'official' [answer](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/1787#issuecomment-318322647) is:

```
PATH_TO_NLTK_DATA=/home/username/nltk_data/
wget https://github.com/nltk/nltk_data/archive/gh-pages.zip
unzip gh-pages.zip
mv nltk_data-gh-pages/ $PATH_TO_NLTK_DATA
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to [issue 1787](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/1787) , I started building RPMs in openSUSE Build Service (OBS) repository [home:jayvdb:nltk_data](https://build.opensuse.org/project/show/home:jayvdb:nltk_data).

For example, for the `punkt` data, the `.spec` file is [here](https://build.opensuse.org/package/view_file/home:jayvdb:nltk_data/nltk-data-punkt/nltk-data-punkt.spec).  It is very easy to copy that for other data packs.

To install from OBS on Fedora Rawhide:

```
dnf config-manager --add-repo http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:jayvdb:nltk_data/Fedora_Rawhide/home:jayvdb:nltk_data.repo
dnf install nltk-data-punkt
```

More download instructions available from the OBS [download page](https://software.opensuse.org//download.html?project=home%3Ajayvdb%3Anltk_data&package=nltk-data-punkt).

Answer (score 0):

The layout of the nltk data is pretty straightforward. Run `nltk.download()` on a computer that has access to github, download the resources you are interested in (if you don't know yet, I recommend the "book" bundle), then find the generated `nltk_data` folder and just copy the hierarchy to your work computer at a location where the nltk can find it. (E.g., see where the downloader tried to install it).

Comment: Like I said, organization has blocked github which is why I am looking for an alternate source of the data which is, hopefully, not blocked. I am working on the solution provided by @m00am below - if it works, I will update on Monday.

Comment: Also, my work computer has no CD drives, no USB ports, and works on the policy that if they haven't used/heard of a site then it definitely is porn

Comment: Give me a break. If you really have no way to copy some of your own data to your work computer, bring your IT people a USB stick with the nltk folders, and ask them to copy it to your computer.